# Flutter Navigate to existing page

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Consider that I have navigation stack **A=>B=>C=>D**

Now I want to bring back page '**B**' from page '**D**' by retaining page '**C**', and navigation stack should be  **A=>C=>D=>B**

Is there any possible way in flutter to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**when you have to navigate from D to B by altering the stack, do the following.**

```
 1. pop until route '/'
 2. push C, then D, and B. That's all , you are good to go.
```

**Note:** If you want to keep the state of intermediate pages, simply lift up the state to the upper level of the tree using any state management technique like Bloc, Provider etc.

To read more about named routes, check the [official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes).

Comment: Could you share a minimum working example using Provider?

Comment: for easy routes yes its feasible but with many dependencies it will create a lot of lag and jank